# Rapid gain in storage use with gitlab not exchanging any files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I am currently running Gitlab CE. I have an issue where it is constantly gaining space,
There is 1 current user (myself). But sitting idle it gains 20gb of usage in under an hour for no apparent reason (not pushing or pulling or even using it, the service is simply live and idle) until eventually it fills my drive (411gb of free space before the installation of Gitlabs. takes less than 24hrs to fill it.).

I cannot locate the source of the issue, google seems to like referring me to size limitations, and that is fine if I needed to increase that which I don't, i have tried to disable some metrics and the safety features such as "Health checks" in an attempt to stop it from doing this but with no success

I have to keep reinstalling it to negate the idle data usage. There is a reason for me setting it up, but I cannot deploy this the way it is. Have any of you experienced this issue? Is there a way around this?

The system current running it: Fedora 36 running the installation on a 500GB SSD, 8 core Ryzen 7 Processor.

any advice to solve this problem would be great. Please note I am not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question:

rsync was scheduled automatically and was in a loop.
Removed rsync, reinstalled it, rescheduled rsync to go on my schedule, removed the older 100 or so back ups and my space has been returned.

for those that are running rsync, just check that it is not running too closely and is detecting that its own backups are there. as the back ups i found were corrupted.